# Count occurrences of four chars in string in php

Tags: php, for-loop, count

Given a string like:

```
ATGGTCCCCTCTTGCCGCGGAAATAATTCCGATATGACCATGGGTAATACTCAAATAATGTAGTTGTGGGAGAGGTATCCACCGTCGGTAGATACTCCTCCGAGCGCTGGTTGGATGAGAGGTTTGTGTGCTTATATTACCGTGAAGCACAGGATCCAAGCCCCAGAGTCAGACCGTCATGTTTGCTTCCGCTGACCGATTACAGCGCTGGAACGTTATAAAGCGCCCACATATTAAGGCACATGACGCTCTCGTAGTTATTTGGGCCGTAATAAATCCAGGGTCTATTTAGCTCGCGCGAGTTTGCAGTGGGCCGACACTAGCAGTTTTGTTCGTAGAGACCTGGCCGAATATTGGCCTGACGAGAAAAGAAGGTGACCACACAATGTAACAGTTCCATATACACCGCACAAAGGGTCATATTATTACCGCCACAACTAGTCCTATCATCTCTGCTTTATCGAATCCAGGGGCAAGAAAAAGTACTGTAGAGTTACCCCGGGTCGGATATACAATGCCGGAAGTGCGTATCGCTACACTCAAGGCCACCCGATACGTCTCCAGCAAGCGGTGGTTGGGGCTGCCTTCAGATGTGTACGTTTCGTGGCAAAGCCTGCTTATATGGTGTTTAATCCAATCGTAGAGAAGGGCGAACCACGATACTGAGCCGACTCGATACGTTGCGGCGAGGCCGTAGCTCCTTTGGGAGTAAGTACAATCGTACACGTGTTAGGCTCTCCCAATATGTCGTAAATCAAACGAAGTATCCAATGGCCTTCCATAAGCCCACCGTCGTCGCATATTAAGGTAGCAGAAGAGATCCGCATGACTAAG
```

I want get four integers (separated by spaces) counting the respective number of times that the symbols 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T' occur in s.

so I was doing

```
<?
$dna = "ATGGTCCCCTCTTGCCGCGGAAATAATTCCGATATGACCATGGGTAATACTCAAATAATGTAGTTGTGGGAGAGGTATCCACCGTCGGTAGATACTCCTCCGAGCGCTGGTTGGATGAGAGGTTTGTGTGCTTATATTACCGTGAAGCACAGGATCCAAGCCCCAGAGTCAGACCGTCATGTTTGCTTCCGCTGACCGATTACAGCGCTGGAACGTTATAAAGCGCCCACATATTAAGGCACATGACGCTCTCGTAGTTATTTGGGCCGTAATAAATCCAGGGTCTATTTAGCTCGCGCGAGTTTGCAGTGGGCCGACACTAGCAGTTTTGTTCGTAGAGACCTGGCCGAATATTGGCCTGACGAGAAAAGAAGGTGACCACACAATGTAACAGTTCCATATACACCGCACAAAGGGTCATATTATTACCGCCACAACTAGTCCTATCATCTCTGCTTTATCGAATCCAGGGGCAAGAAAAAGTACTGTAGAGTTACCCCGGGTCGGATATACAATGCCGGAAGTGCGTATCGCTACACTCAAGGCCACCCGATACGTCTCCAGCAAGCGGTGGTTGGGGCTGCCTTCAGATGTGTACGTTTCGTGGCAAAGCCTGCTTATATGGTGTTTAATCCAATCGTAGAGAAGGGCGAACCACGATACTGAGCCGACTCGATACGTTGCGGCGAGGCCGTAGCTCCTTTGGGAGTAAGTACAATCGTACACGTGTTAGGCTCTCCCAATATGTCGTAAATCAAACGAAGTATCCAATGGCCTTCCATAAGCCCACCGTCGTCGCATATTAAGGTAGCAGAAGAGATCCGCATGACTAAG";
echo substr_count($dna, 'A') . " " .substr_count($dna, 'C') . " " . substr_count($dna, 'G') . " " . substr_count($dna, 'T');

?>
```

But I want to improve the answer, like on perl

```
perl -ne '$,=" ";print y/A//, y/C//, y/G//, y/T//'
```

or doing a efficient loop like in scala:

```
var a,c,g,u = 0
s.foreach {
  case 'A' => a+=1
  case 'C' => c+=1
  case 'G' => g+=1
  case 'U' => u+=1
}
```

is the best option a for loop or can I modify php's function `substr_count`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$result = count_chars($dna);
```

[`count_chars()`](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)

Comment: +1 for using the built-in function instead of some convoluted method.